# Expected value and variance from random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Given the following

$Y_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(μ, σ^2 )$

and

$Y_2=α+βY_1+U \;where \; Y_1 \;and \;U\;is\;independent\;and\;U∼\mathcal{N}(0,v^2)$

Let $μ=350$ and $σ^2 =12365$

How would i calculate the expected value and variance from $Y_2$ ?
And how can i find the distribution of it?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much by definition of expected value: $$E(Y_2) = E(\alpha + \beta Y_1 + U)\\ = E(\alpha) + E(\beta Y_1)+ E(U)\\ = \alpha + \beta E(Y_1) + E(U)$$

And variance:
$$var(Y_2) = E(Y_2^2) - E(Y_2)^2$$
We need to find $E(Y_2^2)$, which is

$$E\left[(\alpha + \beta Y_1 + U)^2\right]\\
= E\left[\alpha^2 + \alpha \beta Y_1 + \alpha U\\ + \alpha \beta Y_1 + \beta^2 Y_1^2 + \beta Y_1 U\\ + \alpha U + \beta Y_1 U + U^2\right].$$

The rest you can probably do with linearity and some arithmetic, I hope this helps.

Edit: Most of the work comes from linearity of the expect value function.

Comment: I updated my post with more information if it makes any difference, cause im not sure i understand

Comment: It seems you added the specific values, but that does not change how we approach the problem. We can solve it abstractly, and then plug in the numbers in the end.

Comment: I see but im not sure how to calculate the expected value and variance using the formulas you gave.

Comment: What is the distribution in this case @BruceET

Answer (score 2):

Because of independence:

$m_Y=E(Y_2)=\alpha +\beta \mu$
$\sigma^2_Y=var(Y_2)=var(\alpha)+var(\beta Y_1)+var (U)$

$=\beta \sigma^2+ v^2$

$Y_2$ ~ $N(m_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$.

You need values for $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $v^2$.

Comment: I think alpha and beta can just be variables and not concrete values

Comment: In that case you can't get a numerical result for mean or variance.

Comment: So what would the expected value and variance be in this case without concrete values? Sorry im not that good at this

Comment: The formulas given in the answer are all you can get.

Comment: If i have to split it up into $E(Y_2) = something$ and $Var(Y_2) = something$ how would i do it from the formulas you've given? and i guess 
$Y_2$ ~ $(_,^2_Y)$ is the distribution but what is $m_Y$ ? and can it be written in another way?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  $E(Y)=m_Y$ and $var(Y)=\sigma^2_Y$ are given as expressions involving the various parameters.  To get anything more, you need to know the values of these parameters.

Comment: What im saying is that i don't know what $m_Y$ is why is it not just $E(Y_2)$ ? So would it be correct to say $E(Y_2)=\alpha +\beta \mu
\sigma^2_Y$ and then $var(Y_2)=var(\alpha)+var(\beta Y_1)+var (U)$ ?

Comment: $m_Y=E(Y_2)=\alpha +\beta \mu$ is given in my answer. $\sigma^2$ is not involved.  $var(Y_2)$ is also given there.  $var(\alpha)=0$, since it is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't given values for $v, a, b,$
so I have supplied some.

The distribution of $Y_2$
is normal.

In my simulation in R below, I have used a million
iterations, so the sample mean and SD of $Y_2$
should agree with the respective population values
to several significant digits--I guess, good enough to
find mistakes in applying the formulas.

```
set.seed(2021)
y1 = rnorm(10^6, 350, 111.198)
u =  rnorm(10^6, 0, 50)
a = 10;  b = 50
y2 = a + b*y1 + u
summary(y2);  sd(y2);  var(y2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  -8248   13765   17511   17513   21263   43899 
[1] 5566.788  # aprx SD(Y2)
[1] 30989134  # aprx Var(Y2)
```

Here are histograms of the simulated distributions
along with the corresponding normal density curves.

[image]

R code for figure.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(y1, prob=T, col="wheat")
 curve(dnorm(x,350,111.198), add=T, lwd=2)
hist(u, prob=T, col="wheat")
 curve(dnorm(x,0,50), add=T, lwd=2)
hist(y2, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 17813, 5566.788), add=T, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

- You say in a comment that you don't follow how to
  calculate some of the results for $Y_2.$
  That is
  not a comment that prompts specific explanations.
- I have had a quick look at answers by @herbsteinberg and @JLF, which seem fine:
  (+1) for each.
- Can you say specifically
  what you don't understand? If there are several
  difficulties, you might start by saying what the first
  couple of them are.

Comment: In @JLF 's answer im not sure what the distribution is

Comment: Do you mean the distribution of $Y_2?$ That's also normal. The purpose is to find its mean and variance.

Comment: I mean in terms of notation, how would it be written,  if im following @JlF 's advice? $ X \sim something$ also is it possible to find the PDF? Probability density function?

Comment: $Y_2 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ where my simulation shows $\mu\approx 17513, \sigma\approx 5566.788,$ and you can get exact values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ using the other answers. Once $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known, plug them into the general formula for a normal density function. (This density function is not a secret; most prob and stat books have it.)